# webpage uses ldap authentication. Cant create a new login form using jquery or angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, authentication, ldap

Please excuse me as i am new to LDAP authentication. I have a web application and the users are allowed to login into the application by using LDAP. A very basic modal pops up when user goes through the login page. this modal shows username and password to enter. If i enter the regular desktop credentials, i am allowed to login.

So, here is my query. the modal which shows username and password field is very basic. I need to create a nice UI showing the user to enter credentials. 
I am planning to use Angular or Jquery to create a nice UI instead of the one which is currently displayed

how can i go about with it ? i guess it is showing me the default here. can i custom it and beautify it ??  Could anyone please suggest some ideas as to how to get it going. Thanks

[a login http://techencoder.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/iis-authentiction-required.png](http://techencoder.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/iis-authentiction-required.png)

Comment: i never heard of LDAP  before but after quick search on google , i don't think you can , it's a 5min searching :p

Comment: @Diptox- i also didnt find anything online. so i thought of posting here. btw, the main page doesnt show any indication that it is using ldap authentication. is it done at the apache server settings ?

Comment: Yes , i think it's like the "Htaccess Authentication"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using HTTP-authentication the popup comes from the browser and you have no chance of changing that.

If you want a "nice" login window you will need to do the whole login process in the application that it is for. And it highly depends on the programming-language used.

But it's not a matter of LDAP but a matter of authentication at the whole

Comment: @heiglandreas- as far as i understand, if i want to create a nice login form, i will have to disable ldap authentication and use some database for logging new users. how do i disable the ldap authentication which is currently there ? do i have to change the http.conf file ?

Comment: No! You got that wrong. You can use an LDAP authentication with your own login form as well! BUT it is far more complex than a HTTP-Auth. You will need some scripting backend like PHP or node or ruby or python or whatever you are familiar with.

Comment: @heiglandreas- i dont intend to use ldap authentication at all. tats y i want to disable it. probably planning to use the normal login with user credentials stored in database. can you share with me if you know how to disable ldap ?

Comment: Ah so thats the intention. I'd check the httpd.conf or  .htaccess-files for anything containing "ldap". You should also check the documentation of mod_auth of the httpd.